# Basic error message in AJAX - Symfony3

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

*I'm working on PhpStorm.2016.3.2 with Symfony3 (Ubuntu 16.04)*

I created an AJAX request that is functional.
The only part i'm missing is the error message.

I have a TextType.php(form) where I can write things and a button where I can search the results, and if it matches, my result appears, but if it is wrong, well nothing happens and I would like to show a message error like **"Oops ! There is nothing !"** while staying on the same page.

**Here is my AJAX request in my view:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.ajax').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'{{ (path("app_sort_restaurants")) }}',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        "city": $('#search_bar_city').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        var bloc = $('#ajax-results');
                        bloc.html('');
                        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            bloc.append('<div><h2>' + data[i]['name'] + '</h2></div>'); 
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

**And here is my controller:**

```
public function ajaxSortRestaurantAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $restaurants = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Restaurant')->findBy(array('city' => $request->request->get('city')));


    $formattedData = array();
    foreach ($restaurants as $restaurant) {
        $formattedData[] = array(
            'name' => $restaurant->getName(),
            'city' => $restaurant->getCity(),
        );
    }
    return new JsonResponse($formattedData);
}
```

I don't know whether I should make a loop like this in the controller or in the AJAX request.
I know there is the `error: function()` missing but I don't know where to put it to make it properly work. I'm a bit lost on the error side.

**To show you what is happening, actually its like this**

*here its working*

[image]

*and here is not*

[image]

*I would like to show "Oops ! There is nothing !" when the search is wrong. Not a blank space like in the example*

If anyone have an advice it would be must appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know there is the error: function() missing but I don't know where to put it to make it properly work.

This is to be added on the same level as `success` and the other options passed to `$.ajax()`, meaning your code could be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ajax').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:'{{ (path("app_sort_restaurants")) }}',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "city": $('#search_bar_city').val()
                },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    var bloc = $('#ajax-results');
                    bloc.html('');
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        bloc.append('<div><h2>' + data[i]['name'] + '</h2></div>'); 
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle error
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Note the parameters, which are described in [the documentation:](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

`xhr`is an XMLHttpRequest, `status` is "a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred.", and `error` is a string that shows the message of the HTTP status code. e.g. "Not Found" for 404.

### Edit after comments

As I understand, having the controller return an error is also an issue. For this to happen, you need to return a Response object with a non-200 status code, or throw an exception.

An example of this is:

```
public function ajaxSortRestaurantAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $restaurants = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Restaurant')->findBy(array('city' => $request->request->get('city')));


    $formattedData = array();
    foreach ($restaurants as $restaurant) {
        $formattedData[] = array(
            'name' => $restaurant->getName(),
            'city' => $restaurant->getCity(),
        );
    }

    if (0 === count($formattedData)) {
        return new Response("", 404);
    }

    return new JsonResponse($formattedData);
}
```

In the case above, a 404 will be returned if there is no formatted data to return.

Once this is done, you can use the error function in the Ajax-option `error` to display an error message where you want it to show.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still don't know how to use this error message. I made some research and I couldn't understand how to make a simple error message appear such as `Oops, nothing here` So how should I do that?

Comment: That is a bit broad of a question, would you like to show that no matter which error is thrown, or only for specific errors? Where would you like to show it?

Comment: I updated my post, you can see the actual result and the wish I want to achieve.

Comment: You could do it the same way as in your success function, where instead of iterating over the data to add things to `bloc`, you just set `bloc.html('<h2>Oops, nothing here</h2>')`. This is done where I commented `//handle error`

Comment: Ok I will try that, I will let you know.

Comment: Hmm sorry I can't seem to make it work :/ It would be good to have an example because I'm new to ajax coding and really I can manage the success but couldn't figure out the errors. Shouldn't I do something in the controller? I'm really lost.

Comment: @crisscross I updated my answer. Does it better answer your question?

Comment: The 404 is working as I get the 404 error in my console(without refreshing the page) But I don't have the message appearing under my search bar saying `Oops, nothing happened` so I don't know it its quite right cause I just want to show a error message. Didn't thought it would be so hard to do that

Comment: Well, have you tried to add the `bloc.html('<h2>Oops, nothing here</h2>')`-line plus the line that defines `bloc` in the error function in your ajax options?

Comment: yes, I wrote this in the error ajax: `error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            var bloc = $('#ajax-results');
                            bloc.html('<h2>Oops, nothing here</h2>')
                        }` maybe it is wrong?

Comment: I tested the code on the following js fiddle, and it seems to work (the url defined for ajax just returns a 404): https://jsfiddle.net/zureeses/ . Do you get an error message?

Comment: Ha its working! :) but the parameters inside the error `xhr, status, error` are not activated, is that normal? do I need so much parameters?

Comment: No, you can omit them if you don't need them. I added them to show the availability of them.

Comment: Ok thank you :) Can you explain me what does this line stand for? `if (0 === count($formattedData)) {
            return new Response("No data", 404);`

Comment: "If there are zero elements in the $formattedData array, return a response with the content "No data", and a 404 status code"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: also `return new Response("No data", 404);` what does "No data" stands for cause I don't understand why this should be here?

Comment: "No data" here is just a string that sets the content of the response body. Normally, this parameter would be the HTML to render a page. In this case where the ajax shows the error message, you could leave it as an empty string.

Comment: Okay understood. Thank a bunch @mdshvero